# How to enable Server access logging in aws through java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to enable server access logging for my newly created S3 buckets using java SDK

I am not able to set the URI properly i think , the error i am getting is please give READ_ACP and WRITE permissions to the destination bucket

I am not able to set the in the S3Grantee any URI as option and also i am not able to set owner

please have a look at my code :
b2 is the actual bucket
destination-bucket is where i want to sent the server logs

```
try {
        // Step 1 - Grant Log Delivery group permission to write log to the target
        // bucket.
        GrantPermissionsToWriteLogsAsync(s3client, b2);

        // Step 2 - Enable logging on the source bucket.
        EnableDisableLoggingAsync(s3client, b2);
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error encountered on server  " + e.getErrorMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Unknown encountered on server", ex.getMessage());
    }

}

private void EnableDisableLoggingAsync(AmazonS3 s3Client, Bucket b2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BucketLoggingConfiguration bucketLoggingConfiguration = new BucketLoggingConfiguration();
    bucketLoggingConfiguration.setDestinationBucketName("destination-bucket");
    bucketLoggingConfiguration.setLogFilePrefix("s3access/");

    SetBucketLoggingConfigurationRequest setBucketLoggingConfigurationRequest = new SetBucketLoggingConfigurationRequest(
            b2.getName(), bucketLoggingConfiguration);
    s3Client.setBucketLoggingConfiguration(setBucketLoggingConfigurationRequest);

}

private void GrantPermissionsToWriteLogsAsync(AmazonS3 s3Client, Bucket b2) {

    try {
        S3AccessControlList bucketACL = new S3AccessControlList();
        AccessControlList aclResponse = s3Client
                .getBucketAcl((new GetBucketAclRequest("destination-bucket")));

        Owner owner = aclResponse.getOwner();
        // aclResponse.setOwner(owner);
        // bucketACL.setOwner(owner);
        // Create a collection of grants to add to the bucket.
        ArrayList<Grant> grantCollection = new ArrayList<Grant>();

        // Grant the LogDelivery group permission to write to the bucket.
        Grant grant2 = new Grant(GroupGrantee.LogDelivery, Permission.Write);
        grantCollection.add(grant2);

        Collection<S3Grant> grants = new ArrayList<S3Grant>();
        S3Grant grant1 = new S3Grant();
        grant1.withPermission(S3Permission.READ_ACP);
        S3Grantee grantee = new S3Grantee();
        grantee.setIdentifier("http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery");
        grant1.withGrantee(grantee);

        S3Grant grant3 = new S3Grant();
        grant3.withPermission(S3Permission.WRITE);
        S3Grantee grantee2 = new S3Grantee();
        grantee.setIdentifier("http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery");
        grant3.withGrantee(grantee2);

        grants.add(grant1);
        grants.add(grant3);

        bucketACL.setGrants(grants);
        // s3Client.setB
        // s3Client.setBucketAcl("destination-bucket", bucketACL);

        SetBucketAclRequest setBucketAclRequest = new SetBucketAclRequest("destination-bucket", aclResponse);

        s3Client.setBucketAcl(setBucketAclRequest);
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {
        logger.error("error :: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your GrantPermissionsToWriteLogsAsync method, not sure what you are doing but it should be like this:

```
    private static void GrantPermissionsToWriteLogsAsync(AmazonS3 s3Client, Bucket b2) {

        try {
            AccessControlList bucketACL = s3Client.getBucketAcl((new GetBucketAclRequest(LOGGING_BUCKET)));

            // Grant the LogDelivery group permission to write to the bucket.
            Grant grant2 = new Grant(GroupGrantee.LogDelivery, Permission.Write);
            // Grant the LogDelivery group permission to read ACP to the bucket.
            Grant grant3 = new Grant(GroupGrantee.LogDelivery, Permission.ReadAcp);

            bucketACL.grantAllPermissions(grant2, grant3);

            SetBucketAclRequest setBucketAclRequest = new SetBucketAclRequest(LOGGING_BUCKET, bucketACL);

            s3Client.setBucketAcl(setBucketAclRequest);
        } catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {
            logger.severe("error :: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```